# Is there any different between $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

I know that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ stands for polynomial in $x$ with coefficients from $\mathbb{C}$, so that is

$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+ \dots a_nx^n \in \mathbb{C}[x]$$

Than what is $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$?

Comment: $\mathbb C[[x]]$ is usually the notation for the ring of formal power series: $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots$. In particular, it contains $\mathbb C[x]$.

Comment: $[[x]]$ is used to signify that you aren't limited to a finite number of terms, i.e. you're allowed "infinite" degree polynomials (without any convergence conditions) (these are called _formal power series_ in the variable $x$ over $\Bbb C$).

Comment: And a big difference is that while the units of $\Bbb C[x]$ are just the nonzero constants, the units of the power-series ring are a much larger group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the ring of formal power series with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series